# Getting Memorry Error while running python script

Tags: python, python3, ubuntu-core

The script i run is doing a concatenation from GLDAS Netcdf file from 2002 to 2017. but i got error like bellow.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 629, in _ensure_cached
    self.array = NumpyIndexingAdapter(np.asarray(self.array))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 610, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/core/indexing.py", line 516, in __array__
    return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 69, in __array__
    return self.func(self.array)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/coding/variables.py", line 140, in _apply_mask
    return np.where(condition, decoded_fill_value, data)
MemoryError
```

could you please tell me what could be the cause?

Regards

Comment: Well it's a memory issue!

Comment: no i don't thnk so i have 40 GB space in this disk i think its some other issue.

Comment: Yes, it is a memory error because it says so in the last line of the error output. FYI: Available disk space is not the same as available memory.

Comment: how i can solve it respected? any idea